# JQUERY set clearInterval after time

Tags: jquery, time, clearinterval

How do I stop it after some time? For example 2 seconds.
Thanks

```
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    var image = this;
        loop = setInterval(function() {
            if (i < images.length - 1) {
                i++;
                $(image).attr('src',images[i]);
            } else {
                i = 0;
                $(image).attr('src',images[i]);
            } 
        }, 40); 

  });
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? You know the method clearInterval(), so where is your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use like this.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   clearInterval(loop);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout()` and `clearInterval()`

```
setTimeout(function(){
   clearInterval(loop);
},2000);
```